# "Special case" records for foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have a mysql table, called `foo` with a foreign key `option_id` constrained to the `option` table.  When I create a `foo` record, the user may or may not have selected an option, and 'no option' is a viable selection.  What is the best way to differentiate between 'null' (i.e. the user hasn't made a selection yet) and 'no option' (i.e. the user selected 'no option')?

Right now, my plan is to insert a special record into the `option` table.  Let's say that winds up with an id of 227 (this table already has a number of records at this point, so '1' isn't available).  I have no need to access this record at a database level, and it would act as nothing more than a placeholder that the foreign key in the `foo` table can reference.

So do I just hard-code '227' in my codebase when I'm creating 'foo' records where the user has selected 'no option'?  The hard-coded id seems sloppy, and leaves room for error as the code is maintained down the road, but I'm not really sure of another approach.

Comment: If you were to have to compare something against any id from your database you'd probably have to hardcode that as well.  So say you have other options in there that you would like to test against, you'd probably need to hard code those in some way, probably as enums or constants, whatever your language allows for.  Yeah it feels sloppy but what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really *have to* differentiate between "no option" and "hasn't made a selection yet"?

If so, you could add an extra column to the 'foo' table "option_selected" that's true if they've selected an option and false if not. That way, you call tell whether a NULL for option_id means "no option" or "not selected yet".